# Sci-fi novel family lives in an island with monsters mountains, the girl travels to a city underwater

Tags: story-identification, novel

The family it’s the style of 1800.
Reminds me of Jane Austin.

One sister gets consumed by the magic of the monsters island. The other travels under the sea to a modern city with her aunt.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you remember any names?  What the cover looked like?